# Undefined Index : website_url and custom url $POST 

Tags: php

Works flawlessly now. Updated code. Thank you newfurniturey.

```
  function foo_options(){
           global $post;
   if (isset($custom['website_url']) && isset($custom['website_url'][0])) {
   $website_url = isset($custom['website_url']) ? $custom['website_url'][0] : '';}
   ?>

<div id="foo-options">
<label>Website URL:</label><input name="website_url" value="<?php echo $website_url; ?>" />     
</div><!--end foo-options--> 
<?php

   }
{

   function update_website_url(){
       global $post;   
       if (($post != null) && isset($_POST['website_url'])) {
       update_post_meta($post->ID, "website_url", $_POST["website_url"]);
     }
  }
```

**Updated** code and bin. http://pastebin.com/2ZWisprm

Comment: Do you mean to reference the superglobal `$_POST` as opposed to `$post`?

Comment: Yeah I guess my question was pretty trivial to adept programmers really sorry about that and will use your link for reference however this answer was spot on and relieved a 2 day search. newfurniturey -thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the issues in-order, regarding the following line:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, "website_url", $_POST["website_url"]);
```

`trying to access a property of a non-object` applies to `$post->ID`. The only way this error can occur is if `$post` is not an object (such as an array), or if it's `null`.

The `undefined index` error applies to `$_POST["website_url"]`; This will happen when either your form is not currently being POSTed, or the field-name does not exist in the current POST data.

I do not know what object is supposed to be within your `$post` variable, so the following is just a guess, but try the following update:

```
function update_website_url(){
    global $post;   
    if (($post != null) && isset($_POST['website_url'])) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "website_url", $_POST["website_url"]);
    }
}
```

This will make sure `$post` is not null, and by assumption that it is a proper object, and that the `website_url` index has been set. You may want to increase the check to use `!empty()` instead of `isset()`, but the above should resolve your error (unless `$post` is an array, or other non-object data type).

Comment: Works beautifully but is now throwing Undefined index: website_url for line 4. I tried your previous code but it gave the error message and put the error code inside the url input box. It's like mole wacking pop one another pops up I can't win hehe..

Comment: My previous answer should technically be applicable to your line 4; using `isset($custom['website_url'])` would resolve the `undefined index` error. If you never declare `$website_url`, per the `isset()` returning false, your `<?php echo $website_url; ?>` will throw a new error about an `undefined variable $website_url;` Try, instead of previous answer: `$website_url = isset($custom['website_url']) ? $custom['website_url'][0] : '';`

Comment: Updated up top. Also just wanted to say thank you. I realize it requires valuable time to help a novice like me and seriously, I am really appreciative. Although I have had experience with isset checks before I could not grasp how to achieve it with $POST. Thanks again.